# How do I check if the user is interacting with select menu and disable it in discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, drop-down-menu, discord.js

I want that when the user is interacting with the select menu it should work and then it should disable it after a few seconds when the user stops interacting with it.

This is just the idea how the Dank Memer bot Help command work.

What my command is doing:
The command works as a help command that is getting all the files in the sub-folder of the command folder and giving the usage, name and description of the command. It edits the embed when the user selects an option in select menu and the option are the sub-folders of the command folder.

So I have done this till now:

```
const { MessageEmbed, Message, MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu, MessageButton } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const prefix = require("../../config.json").PREFIX;

module.exports = {
  name: "help",
  description: "Get All The Commands!",
  usage: "help",
  cooldown: 1000 * 5,
  category: "Help Commands!",
  /**
   * @param {Message} message
   * 
   */
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const sizeOfCat = fs.readdirSync("./Commands - Staff/");

    const OldEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor({
        name: "Commands! =>",
        iconURL: `${message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`
      })
      .setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`)
      .setTitle(" Need help? Select The Category You Want To =>")
      .setDescription(
        `
        **\`Hello Dear ${message.member.user.username}, Please Select Your Category According To Your Choice!\`**

        **How To Use =>**
        \`1) Click The Select Menu Down Below.\`
        \`2) You Will See Many Categories, Click Your Category You Want To View.\`
        \`3) The Embed Will Be Edited And You Can See Your Commands According To Category.\`

        *Note => The Select Menu And The Button Will Be Disabled Automatically After 6 Seconds!*

        **Total Categories Are: ${sizeOfCat.length}**
        `
      )
      .setColor("BLURPLE")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({
        text: `Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, 
        iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
      })

      const homeButton = new MessageActionRow()
      .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId("Home")
        .setLabel("Back To Home!")
        .setStyle("PRIMARY")
        .setEmoji("️")
      )

      const EmojisCat = {
        "Other Commands!": "",
        "Help Commands!": "",
        "Moderation Commands!": "⚒️",
        "Owner Commands!": ""
      };

      const selectMenu = new MessageActionRow()
      .addComponents(
        new MessageSelectMenu()
        .setCustomId("Help-Menu")
        .setPlaceholder(`Click To View The Categories Of The Commands!`)
        .addOptions([
          client.categoriesCommands.map((cat) => {
            return {
              label: `${cat[0].toUpperCase() + cat.slice(1)}`,
              value: cat,
              emoji: EmojisCat[cat],
              description: `Click To View The Commands Of This Categories!`,
            }
          })
        ])
      );

    await message.reply({
      content: "**There You Go, Check The List Of Categories!**",
      embeds: [OldEmbed],
      components: [selectMenu, homeButton]
    })
    .then(async (msg) => {

      let filter = i => i.member.id === message.member.id;
      let colletor = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filter });

      let timeout = null;
      colletor.on("collect", async (i) => {
        if (!i.member.id === message.member.id) {
          await msg.reply({
            content: `**Its Not Your Turn Of Using The Command Menu Or The Command (\`${prefix}help\`) Is Not Runned By You! Dum Dum.**`,
            ephemeral: true,
          });
        } else {

          if (i.isButton()) {
            await i.deferUpdate();
            if (i.customId === "Home") {
              msg.edit({ embeds: [OldEmbed] })
            }
          }

          if (i.isSelectMenu()) {
            if (i.customId === "Help-Menu") {
              await i.deferUpdate();
              let [ directory ] = i.values;
              let totalCdms = client.categoriesCommands.filter(cmd => cmd.category === directory).map(cmd => cmd.size);
              let command = client.categoriesCommands.filter(cmd => cmd.category === directory).map(cmd => cmd.length) + 1;

              const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor({
                  name: "AwesomeSMP Commands! =>",
                  iconURL: `${message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`
                })
                .setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true })}`)
                .setTitle(` Need help? Here Are All Of My ${directory} Commands:`)
                .setDescription(
                  `
                  **\`Here Are One Of My [${directory} Category] Commands =>\`**

                  **Total Commands In ${directory} Are: ${totalCdms}**
                  `
                )
                .setColor("BLURPLE")
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({
                  text: `Requested by ${message.author.tag}`, 
                  iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
                })
                
              client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === directory)
              .map((cmd) => {
                embed.addField(
                  `\n**\nCommmand-${command++}** =>\n\`${prefix}${cmd.name}\``,
                  `   **Description:** *${cmd.description.toUpperCase() || "*None*"}*\n   **Usage:** *${prefix} ${cmd.usage || "None"}*\n`
                  ,true
                );
              })

              await msg.edit({
                embeds: [embed]
              });
              
              if (!i.message.member.id === i.isSelectMenu()) {
                if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(async () => {
                  selectMenu.components[0].setDisabled(true);
                  homeButton.components[0].setDisabled(true);
          
                  await msg.edit({
                    embeds: [OldEmbed],
                    components: [selectMenu, homeButton]
                  });
                }, 6000);
              }

            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

There are no errors till now.

Comment: Your timeout to disable the components after inactivity is inside your collector's `collect` handler, meaning the inactivity timeout will only start *after* any input has been collected. I assume you want this timeout to be outside the collector, so it will disable itself after the timeout even if no input has been collected.

Comment: I don't get what @Cannicide wants to say. Is he telling me to move my timeout outside the collector also I have written that I want my help command to work as Dank Memer Help command. So if they did not know what is Dank Memer I would suggest them to use there help command and check that when the user stops interacting with the drop down menu, after few seconds the drop down menu disables itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "interacting"? By that do you mean something along the lines of "x seconds after the user last selected a value, disable the menu"? You stated, "if they did not know what is Dank Memer I would suggest them to use there help command and check that", but it would be much easier for answerers if you simply include that highly relevant information inside your question itself instead of requiring us to get Dank Memer and try out the command ourselves. I agree with @halfer that most readers probably didn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Based on what you are saying, I think all you're looking for is declaring an empty variable (for example, named `timeout`) before your collector, and each time the collector collects something you do `clearTimeout(timeout)` if `timeout` is defined, and then afterwards you set `timeout` equal to your current `setTimeout()` statement. This will act as essentially resetting the timer of the timeout each time a menu value is selected.

Comment: @Cannicide I still don't get it ._., can you give me an example so I can get what are you saying? I just get that you are telling me to move my `timeout` out of the collector and if people aren't getting what I am saying, at least you get it and then halfer can edit my message and can explain more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the code in the question now work? If so, you will need to roll it back to the last good question state. Readers newly seeing the answer now will be confused at the solution presented if the question no longer contains an example of a problem.

Comment: Since there was no response to my March 10th comment, I have rolled this back to the point at which I think it was still a question. Feel free to make any amendments to it, but **please do not add any solution material** into the post - the point of Q&A is that questions remain questions, so that future readers can see how the answer(s) below them are the solution to the problem presented.

Comment: (If you want to add a self-answer to record how you solved the problem, then you can post your own below).

Comment: first I did reply to your comment and deleted it because It was filled with comments and I did remove the solution when you told me about that "Does the code in the question now work?" comment and just wrote fixed by Cannicide and now I edited it to remove some personal info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, it looks like all you want to do is declare an empty variable (for example, named `timeout`) before your collector, and each time the collector collects something you do `clearTimeout(timeout)` if `timeout` is defined, and then afterwards you set `timeout` equal to your current `setTimeout()` statement. That is, if I'm understanding your question correctly. Ignore my initial comment about moving the timeout entirely outside the collector, as that was probably not what you were looking for with your question (I believe I initially misunderstood your question -- however, if this answer is still not what you are looking for, my initial comment may instead be exactly what you are looking for).

Now for the answer to your question. Here is an example of what I am talking about with the process I described above and in the comments. I'm just going to show the relevant parts of the code so that you know where everything is happening, without having to sift through dozens of lines to find my changes (and note in the future, please only include the parts of your code that are relevant to your question -- i.e. just your collector and the `collector.on("collect")` handler in this case).

```js
async function disableAll() {
    selectMenu.components[0].setDisabled(true);
    homeButton.components[0].setDisabled(true);
  
    await msg.edit({
        embeds: [OldEmbed],
        components: [selectMenu, homeButton]
    });
}

let timeout = setTimeout(disableAll, 6000);
colletor.on("collect", async (i) => {
               
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(disableAll, 6000);

});
```

Here is what this code does, step by step. Every time a user interacts with the select menu:

1. Check if a `timeout` has already been started. If so, clear it. (If no timeout has been created yet, no clearing of timeouts needs to occur).
2. Create a new `timeout` using `setTimeout()`. The new timeout will disable the select menu after 6 seconds.
3. If the user interacts with the select menu again before the 6 seconds is over, the process starts over from step 1. The timeout created in the previous step will be cleared and another one will be created in its place, with the time reset to 6 seconds.
4. If no user interacts with the select menu again before the 6 seconds is over, the select menu simply gets disabled once the time runs out. This means the menu will only disable 6 seconds after the user last interacted with the menu.

In response to your comment expressing confusion over what I was trying to tell you in the comments, I hope this step-by-step explanation clears up what I meant.

### Edit

Removed the `if` statement that checks the case `!i.message.member.id === i.isSelectMenu()`. As I explained in the comments, `!i.message.member.id` is always `false` here, and `i.isSelectMenu()` is always `true` here, so the removed `if` statement was checking if `false === true` (which is obviously a statement that is always false).

### Edit 2

As I mentioned in my very first comment on this question, i.e. the initial comment that the OP was confused about, the original timeout functionality was inside the collector. This meant that all of the code to disable the select menu and button would only execute after a value in the menu was initially selected. In other words, the menu would not disable itself after 6 seconds of no interaction; it would only disable itself 6 seconds after the last interaction. If the user did not use the select menu at all, no disabling would occur after 6 seconds. This is what I meant with my original comment. I have modified the answer to move the initial timeout outside the collector. Now, it will disable after 6 seconds if the user either: a) has not interacted at all; or b) last interacted over 6 seconds ago.

Comment: thank you I get it now what you are telling and I will also test it

Comment: Hey I used your way and it did not worked can you see my edited code and tell what I am doing wrong cause it did not disable it after 6 seconds.

Comment: I am not sure. You will need to do some debugging. I believe the logic used in this answer works fine, so the problem is most likely that this timeout code is never actually reached in your code. Try putting a `console.log` right before the `let timeout = null` line and see if it ever logs anything. If it doesn't, there is something wrong with your code's logic that is preventing this code from executing. The problem could be something like the statement `!i.message.member.id === i.isSelectMenu()` not returning the value you expect (this may be a good thing to log as well).

Comment: Ok I did it as you told me and this was the result for `timeout` it said "null" and for `!i.message.member.id === i.isSelectMenu()` it said "false".

Comment: As I suspected. Take a look at your logic for doing `!i.message.member.id === i.isSelectMenu()`. Not quite sure what the point of that line is. `!i.message.member.id` will always be `false` (because the ID of the member that used the select menu will always be defined), so currently the timeout code will only execute if `i.isSelectMenu()` is `false` (but this statement is inside an `if (i.isSelectMenu())`, so `i.isSelectMenu()` is always `true`). So basically you have an `if (false === true)` here. You should probably remove/edit that line. Try it out, I'll edit it out of this answer as well.

Comment: Oh I just saw that this code works only when a user interacts with it, it doesn't work when user calls the command and does not interact with it hence it does not disable it but I want both of the things work I want that it should disable it after when user stops interacting with it and disable it when user does not even interact with it.

Comment: Well... that was exactly what I was talking about with my very first comment on your question about moving the timeout outside of the collector. At any rate, the change you need to make is very simple. On the line that says `let timeout = null`, just replace `null` with the `setTimeout()` lines. I'll edit this answer once again to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that you need to add `idle: amount`, where amount is your time in milliseconds, in your collector.

```
let collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter: filter, idle: 6000 });
```

This will stop the collector after 6 seconds from the last interaction, or 6 seconds after the command being launched.

You can also use `time: amount` to stop the collector after a specific amount of time passes.

Comment: Thanks, this also helps but I already got my answer and its working fine for now and I don't want to re-write the code, if I get any errors in future I will definitely refer to your code to solve it.