# TypeError: interaction.isStringSelectMenu is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a running discordjs bot and want to add a select menu. For that menu I need a check for that interaction. I copy and pasted this code block from the discordjs guide, but I'm getting this error. Other discordjs functions on `interaction` run without problems like `interaction.isChatInputCommand()`.

Error:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: interaction.isStringSelectMenu is not a function
```

edit:
that is the link to the code block I'm referring: https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#building-and-sending-select-menus

Comment: maybe similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239947/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-is-interacting-with-select-menu-and-disable-it-in-dis

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: You say " this code block from the discordjs guide" but there is no link or code block. Can you post that code that you're following?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros my version is 14.6.0

Comment: I think it's available from 14.7.0 or 14.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `discord.js` v14.6.0, the `isStringSelectMenu()` type guard doesn't exist yet. This type guard was added later in v14.7.0. But for your current version, you can use `isSelectMenu()` to check if the interaction was of a `SelectMenu`.